# Saving Sessions in SSL Encrypted Cookies vs. Client Certificates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, persistence, certificate, single-sign-on

**Background:** From a desktop application, users will navigate to an SSL-encrypted web portal where they will have to enter a username / password if it's their first time logging in. I want to be able to securely persist their user session. I was thinking of using encrypted cookies, storing their username and a unique session token / key, but was wondering what benefits client certificates offered in terms of security.

The way I see understand it currently:

**Encrypted cookies:**

- Saved on the user's machine just like any other cookie
- Since the entire site is SSL, the contents of the cookie cannot be tampered with
- Easily implementable
- When a user logs in again, invalidate the token / key and issue a new one

*Problems:*

- Anyone attempting to access the web portal on the computer with a saved session will be able to, but this is a problem with any persisted session, right?
- How do I know that computer A is computer A and not just computer B that copied computer A's cookie?

**Client Certificates:**

- A pain in the ass to install
- Will uniquely identify that person's computer (or can it be restricted to the user account) to the web portal
- If the client certificate is stolen, then the account is compromised

**Question:** For persisting user sessions with the utmost security, would encrypted cookies be sufficient or would I need to install client certificates? How do they differ?

Comment: I'm not sure that either method is great "with the utmost security". Persisted sessions can never be all that secure, as it's always going to be possible for someone who gets access to a client machine to waltz straight into your system, be that un-authed users, the office cleaner, whoever. Assuming that isn't a problem, then the differences in security between the two solutions won't be that significant.

Answer (score 1):

2-face-authentication (client certificates) does not mean a persisted sessions. Each time the user visits the page the client certificate is used to authenticate against the site. Depending on the client policies (or AD) the user might enter a PIN to be able to submit the certificate or choose from a list of certificates installed to the certificate store.